# Converting the given minutes to hh:mm:ss format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, management-studio-express

Here's my database structure (simplified):

```
if db_id('MovieDB') is null
    create database MovieDB;

go

use MovieDB;

go

if object_id(N'Movies', N'U') is null
create table Movies
(
    MovieID         bigint          not null    identity    primary key,
    Duration        time(7)         not null,
);

insert into Movies values
(format(dateadd(minute, 142, 0), N'hh:mm:ss', 'en-US'));
```

I inserted the duration as minutes and I need it to be converted to `hh:mm:ss` format. However, with the execution of this I get `02:22:00.0000000`.

How can I format the date to get just `02:22:00`?

Comment: Show the code you are using to look at the data.

Comment: `SELECT TOP (1000) [MovieID] ,[Duration] FROM [MovieDB].[dbo].[Movies]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert to a time:

```
select convert(time, dateadd(minute, 142, 0))
```

Or, if you want the value as a string, you can use the old-fashioned `convert()`:

```
select convert(varchar(8), dateadd(minute, 142, 0), 108)
```

But I'm confused.  You are storing the value as a `time` with 7 digits of fractional seconds.  Then you are complaining about seeing the fractional seconds.

Fractional seconds probably don't make a difference for movie times, so why not just use:

```
Duration        time(0)         not null,
```

Comment: yeah actually it shouldn't be `time(7)`, but after changing to `time` or `time(0)` i still get the 7 zeros

Comment: @user3132457 . . . You can convert the value to a string (as in the first example) to get what you exactly want.

Comment: it's still the same

Comment: @user3132457 . . . It is impossible to get fractional seconds with `convert(varchar(8), duration, 108)`.  You need to do this when you *select* the data, not when you insert it.